# How would I rewrite this code using a for loop instead of using the [...Array].map() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the code, it uses map to go through and do the function. However if I want to make it do a loop using for (let i = 0) how would I go about that?

```
function randomArrayGenerator(n, low, high) {
  var randoms = [...Array(n)].map(() => Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
  return randoms;
}

console.log(randomArrayGenerator(10, 23, 51));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By this way

```js
function randomArrayGenerator(n, low, high) {
    let randoms = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        randoms.push(Math.random() * (high - low) + low);
    }
    
    return randoms;
}

console.log(randomArrayGenerator(10, 23, 51));
```